Check if the sample mean squared is an unbiased estimator for the mean squared
My professor gave us the following problem :
Let $ \{ y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_N \}$ be a random sample drawn from $N(\theta, \sigma^2)$ where $ \sigma^2$ is known.
We want to check if this estimator is unbiased for $\theta^2$ and if it may be consistent. We want to compute the ML estimate of $\theta ^2$.
Since the ML estimator of $\theta$ is $\hat{\theta}_N = \bar{y}_N $, we could get the ML estimate of $\theta^2$ using the invariance principle by setting $\hat{\theta}_N^2 = \bar{y}_N^2$.
And then it provides as solution:
$$ E_\theta [\bar{y}_N^2] = \frac{(N-1)^2 + N}{N^2} \theta^2 + \frac{\sigma^2}{N}$$
which I believe to be wrong since this is what I did:
$$E_\theta [\bar{y}_N^2] = E (\frac{1}{N^2} \sum (y_i^2)) = \frac{1}{N^2} \sum E(y_i)^2 = \frac{1}{N^2} (\sum Var(y_i) + E(y_i)^2) = \frac{1}{N^2} (N \sigma^2 + N^2 \theta^2) = \frac{\sigma^2}{N} + \theta^2$$
which becomes unbiased as N goes to infinity.
Is my solution correct?

Indeed,
$$E(\bar{y}^2)= Var(\bar{y}) + E(\bar{y})^2 = \frac{\sigma^2}{N} + \theta^2$$
This is not unbiased for $\theta^2$, but is indeed asymptotically unbiased. Since the variance tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, this implies the estimator is consistent.

So the correct answer is mine and not the one given by my professor, right?

@Fras yes it is

Perfect thank you
